# JunOS ssh debugging

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, ssh

Our Junipers will not accept my ssh keys when I provide them from my favorite Windows client.

On a FreeBSD machine, I would restart sshd with the -d flag and just watch the output to discover why the keys were not palatable.

Can I do something similar on JunOS?

Comment: `show log messages | match ssh` may give you some hints on what's wrong. I don't think you can run sshd in debug mode.

Comment: Bingo! "error: key_read: uudecode .... failed" Re-copying in key fixed it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, Teun Vink's comment above provided the necessary clue.

`show log messages | match ssh`

revealed:

`error: key_read: uudecode .... failed`

The key had been mis-copied into the config.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no traceoptions for SSH that I'm aware of.  If you have access to a *nix machine with your SSH keys loaded, you could try connecting with:

```
ssh -vvv user@router
```

and see which keys are offered and which identities are matched.

If you're using PuTTY, then right-click on the window title and select **Event Log** to get similar output.

Comment: PuTTY works. openssh  from FreeBSD machines work. The only thing that fails is SecureCRT and the trace from that application shows nothing untoward (key-xchange algorithm, keys offered, auth failed). However,  SecureCRT auths fine to  ciscos and Cienas. The Juniper doesn't like what SecureCRT is offering and I  think I need the sshd on the Juniper to tell me why.

Comment: What does "show configuration system services ssh" say?

Comment: root-login deny-password;
protocol-version [ v2 v1 ];
connection-limit 5;
rate-limit 10;